# No value appears in editText in my Android App

Tags: android, xml

I'am new on develloping with Java/XML and I'm facing a strange problem with this app.
The code compiles well and the app appears the way I want. But some textViews of the pricipal activity do not display value that I type on the keyboard.
Tried to understand what going on by reading the LogCat but I don't really understand where is the problem.
Can anybody help?
Many thx in advance
Here is the XML code:

```
        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ScrollView    
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <HorizontalScrollView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/TheTable"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12" >        

             <TableRow
                 android:id="@+id/tbRow1"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/spot"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

              <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/div"               
                    android:text="@string/div"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />      

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rate"
                    android:text="@string/Rate"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tbRow2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/spotText"
                    android:hint="@string/Spot"
                    android:gravity="center"      
                    android:inputType="numberSigned"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/divRate"
                    android:hint="@string/divRate"
                    android:gravity="center"    
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/IR"
                    android:hint="@string/IRate"
                    android:gravity="center"    
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

            </TableRow>        

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tbRow3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/product"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                android:text="@string/product"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:textColor="@color/white" />


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/strike"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                android:text="@string/strike"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/white" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/maturity"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                android:text="@string/maturity"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/white" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vol"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/volatility"
                                android:textColor="@color/white" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/Qty"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/Quantity"
                                android:textColor="@color/white" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/price"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/price"
                                android:textColor="@color/white" />
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tbRow4" >
                            <Spinner 
                                android:id="@+id/spin1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:dropDownSelector="@string/Product"
                                android:prompt="@string/Product"
                                android:entries="@array/Array"
                                android:background="@color/SpinColor"
                                android:textSize="10sp"/>
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/K1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="K"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="10sp"/>
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/T1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="T"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="10sp"/>
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/Vol1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="Vol"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="10sp"/>
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/Qty1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="Qty"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="10sp"/>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/Px1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                                android:textSize="10sp"/>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tbRow9">                
                             <Button 
                                android:id="@+id/delBtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:text="@string/delete"/>
                            <Button 
                                android:id="@+id/addBtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:text="@string/Add"/>

                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>

               </HorizontalScrollView>
            </ScrollView>            

        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d54278 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d54278 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    01-07 07:46:12.465: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437): null
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d54278 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    01-07 07:46:12.484: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d57990 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d57990 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    01-07 07:46:12.524: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437): null
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d57990 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    01-07 07:46:12.544: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    01-07 07:46:13.445: E/Trace(12824): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    01-07 07:46:14.484: E/InputDispatcher(8021): channel '4104a3e8 com.example.lilpricer/com.example.lilpricer.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    01-07 07:46:23.534: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
    01-07 07:46:33.184: E/Trace(12840): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    01-07 07:46:34.434: E/Trace(12853): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    01-07 07:46:38.474: E/Trace(12868): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    01-07 07:46:39.904: E/Trace(12881): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    01-07 07:46:42.026: E/Trace(12894): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    01-07 07:46:45.554: E/Trace(12911): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    01-07 07:46:48.954: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
    01-07 07:46:50.244: E/Trace(12941): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    01-07 07:46:59.634: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d61f28 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d61f28 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    01-07 07:47:03.514: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437): null
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d61f28 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    01-07 07:47:03.704: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d49c40 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d49c40 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    01-07 07:47:03.744: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437): null
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d49c40 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    01-07 07:47:03.764: E/StrictMode(8437):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d7c008 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d7c008 that was originally bound here
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    01-07 07:47:53.673: E/ActivityThread(8437):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

Comment: Unless you are editing the AOSP mail client, that stack trace has nothing to do with you.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got your problem. it looks like you have given the TextColor for all EditTexts as white and when you type some text, nothing is visible as EditText has white background.

Replace this attribute `android:textColor="@color/white"` in your EditTexts with `android:textColor="@android:color/black"`

Comment: @vsk study my answer properly. I said the questionaire that textColor was set white and when text enter it will be shown white. by default an edittext background is white as well as text is white. white inside white everything white